# multiple definition of clocktype::clocktype()

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a class that will run this main program but I'm getting the errors:

[image]

Can anyone explain cause/solution to said errors? Sorry for similar question to last but im trying to refresh on c++ for my course and i've forgotten alot.

Here is my main:

```
int main()
{
    clockType c1(15, 45, 30), c2(3, 20);  // hour, min, sec
    cout << "c1 is " << c1;   // add whatever to beautify it
    cout << "c2 is " << c2;
    cout << "c1+c2 is " <<  c1+c2;
    c2 = c1+c1;
    cout << "c1+c1 is " << c2;
}
```

Here is my header file:

```
#ifndef CLOCKTYPE_H
#define CLOCKTYPE_H
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>


class clockType
{
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const clockType& out);
friend clockType operator+(const clockType& one, const clockType& two);
public:
    clockType();
    clockType(int hours, int minutes, int seconds);
    clockType(int hours, int minutes);
    void setTime(int hours, int minutes, int seconds);
    void getTime(int& hours, int& minutes, int& seconds);
    void printTime();
    void incrementhr();
    void incrementmin();
    void incrementsec();
private:
    int hrs;
    int mins;
    int secs;
};

#endif // CLOCKTYPE_H
```

Here is my cpp file:

```
#include "clockType.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

clockType::clockType()
{
    hrs = 0;
    mins = 0;
    secs = 0;
}

clockType::clockType(int hours, int minutes, int seconds)
{
    setTime(hours, minutes, seconds);
}

clockType(int hours, int minutes)
{
    hrs = hours;
    mins = minutes;
    secs = 0;
}

void clockType::setTime(int hours, int minutes, int seconds)
{
    if (0 <= hours && hours < 24)
        hrs = hours;
    else
        hrs = 0;
    if (0 <= minutes && minutes < 60)
        mins = minutes;
    else
        mins = 0;
    if(0 <= seconds && seconds < 60)
        secs = seconds;
    else
        secs = 0;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const clockType& out)
{
    os << "Hour is " << out.hrs << "Minute is " << out.mins << "Seconds is " << out.secs;
    return os;
}

clockType operator+(const clockType& one, const clockType& two)
{
    clockType three;
    three.hrs = one.hrs + two.hrs;
    three.mins = one.mins + two.mins;
    three.secs = one.secs + two.secs;
    return three;
}
```

Comment: Link to image isn't there.

Comment: You haven't even fixed the problems identified by answers to your last question.

Answer (score 1):

One of several issues with the code is that you're missing the scope in the definition of one of the constructors (line 18 in the clockType.cpp file):

```
clockType(int hours, int minutes)
```

should be

```
clockType::clockType(int hours, int minutes)
```

changing that makes the code compile for me.

Also, in the cpp file you're including iostream twice... and including ostream when you already include iostream is probably not needed as the compiler most likely will include ostream with iostream anyway (even though the standard makes no guarantee).

Comment: If the standard makes no guarantee then you should code to that. Standard does not say it is included, ergo you should explicitly include it. Don't rely on implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing is that there are multiple definitions of the `clockType` methods. There are only single definitions in the code you present, so the problem must be in how you are compiling and linking.

Perhaps you have two source files that define `clockType` methods. Or perhaps you are linking multiple object files with definitions for the `clockType` methods. The answer will be found in your compilation command.

On top of that, the two parameter constructor for `clockType` has the wrong signature, as you were told in your previous question. It should be:

```
clockType::clockType(int hours, int minutes)
```

You are also missing definitions for a number of other methods in the class.

Comment: Okay, i keep getting these compiler/linker errors and i have no idea what's wrong, can someone help me out?